# How to show summ of several variables. PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Good day.
I have 2 tables in psql db.

1st orders: orderid, status
2nd goods: orderid, price

Orderid goods = orderid from orders.

I can have one order (orderid not replies in orders table)    but i can have several goods with one orderid.

I want to see with SELECT next view:
Orderid, allprice (if we have several goods, their prices must be summaruzed to one).

How i can do it?

Comment: Please include the query you tried along with sample input and output data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`SUM` aggregate function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-aggregate.html) and [`GROUP BY` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY):

```
SELECT
    orderid,
    SUM(price)
FROM
    orders
    JOIN goods
    USING (orderid)
GROUP BY
    orderid;
```